# Dynamic ID's for HTML ELements

Tags: html

Lets say in an aspx page I have a for loop and within the for loop I want to create  elements. How can I generate id 's dynamically for them.

For instance if I have :

```
    <div>
    <% Foreach (item in itemCollection) { %>
    {
       <table>
      <tr>
      here I want to create td elements with id as reconText1 reconText2...the numbers at the end I get by incrementing the index.

    </tr>
   </table>
    }
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `for` loop with index or a separate index variable with `foreach`:

```
<% int i = 1; %>
<% foreach (item in itemCollection) { %>
    <tr>
        <td id="reconText<%= i %>">...</td>
    </tr>
    <% i++; %>
<% } %>
```